# Fast way to switch only between local Git branches in the command line?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I've used Git for over a decade and I do everything from the command line. I have aliases for many things and generally like my workflow.

But one pain point: switching branches is tedious on my current project. `git switch <tab>` tries to autocomplete from my local branches **and** all the current remote branches and old remote branches that people forgot to delete:

```
zsh: do you wish to see all 251 possibilities (126 lines)?
```

So I type `git branch` to see my local ones and then copy and paste the rather long branch name that follows our team's conventions.

I don't want to adopt a whole GUI or editor plugin, but I'd like a faster way.

Is there a command like `git switch` that will only list local branches - the ones shown by `git branch` (not `git branch -a`)? Or a command-line tool that would let me use arrows to select a branch to check out?

Comment: `git switch refs/heads/<TAB>`?

Comment: i use `shift + tab` for suggestions in zsh config, `tab` for moving between suggestions. So, even in case of 251 possibilities just pressing and keeping `tab` key will enumerate them quickly.

Comment: Try to use [fig](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/fig) plugin for zsh. I believe it should support git commands, but haven't used it yet.

Comment: Actually, this makes me wonder if it would be possible to tell (for the terminal / auto-completion) <tab> from fast <tab><tab> so that it could show local and all branches depending on which way it went. Might be a nice research line.

Comment: @Ryan can you elaborate on the zsh config setup? Got a link?

Comment: @NathanLong i use Arch Linux, these is my plugins line `plugins=(git archlinux zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-autosuggestions)` from .zshrc. Good starting point for keybindings: [zsh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zsh) (3.4 section - keybindings). The only customization for keybindings i added: `bindkey '^I' autosuggest-accept`

Comment: Looks like https://superuser.com/questions/1722576/configure-git-completion-for-checkout-to-only-show-local-branches is the same question. A bit of a rabbit hole though.

Comment: Why are branches preserved after being merged?

Comment: @Ryan Mostly by accident. They shouldn't be, but I can't police everyone. I've requested a GitHub feature to bulk delete old branches: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/68425

Comment: @NathanLong Seems like it's less effort to clean up the branches than to constantly work around them. I have an alias to clean up local merged branches. `merged = !sh -c 'git branch --merged | grep -v ^*'` shows what branches have been merged into the current branch and `rm-merged = !sh -c 'git merged | xargs git branch -d'` deletes them. It could easily be adopted to also clean up their remote branches.

Comment: @Schwern Yep, I like that trick, but in this case I'm working on a team where people do squash merges, so `git branch --merged` doesn't detect merges. And cleaning up other people's branches is tedious at best and dangerous at worst.

Answer (score 4):

## Here's a script

I didn't see an easy answer, so I hacked up a zsh script. If saved on the `PATH` as `git-sb`, it can be run as a subcommand: `git sb`.

Usage looks like:

```
~: sb
1 foo
2 bar
3 main
4 release
5 baz
switch to which?
```

If I enter `4`, I see:

```
4
Switched to branch 'release'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release'.
```

The script is:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
# Git subcommand to switch between a list of branches. `git sb`.

# initialize an index and an empty array of branches
i=1
branches=()

# list local branches in plain format and loop through them
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ | while read -r branchname ; do
  branches+=($branchname)
  echo "$i $branchname"
  ((i++))
done

echo "switch to which?"
# read the user's selected integer 
read selected_index
git switch ${branches[$selected_index]}
```

Comment: How do I set myself up to use this script?

Comment: @matt Basic way: save it to a file called `switch_branches` (or whatever you want) and `chmod u+x switch_branches` to make it executable. If it's in `~/scripts/` you could then do `~/scripts/switch_branches` to run it. But you really want to put it into your `$PATH` somewhere so you can just call `switch_branches` and maybe add `alias sb='switch_branches'` to your `.zshrc` to allow calling with `sb`. Personally I have a repo for my dotfiles and a `bin/` folder in it for this kind of script, and I add that folder to my `$PATH` in my `.zshrc` using `export PATH="$HOME/.dotfiles/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: Yeah nah. :) I folded it into my .zshrc as a function.

Comment: To the `git for-each-ref` command in this script you can add `--sort=-committerdate` to sort by recency, and `--count=10` to show only ten. I saved this as a script (on my `$PATH`) called `git-b`, so I run it with `git b`.

Comment: @Raffi Ooh, I didn't know that `git-whatever` executables show up as subcommands. And nice suggestions on the flags. Thanks! Edited.